# Facing error while Altering table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I was creating tables in PostgreSQL. Then I had to use an column as foreign key so I altered my table to define that column as foreign key. 
But I got an error at `"WITH"`,

```
ALTER TABLE Account  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_Account_AccountCPCMapping FOREIGN KEY(nAccountCPCMappingID)
REFERENCES AccountCPCMapping (nAccountCPCMappingID);
```

I am getting error like,

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE Account  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_Account...
```

Please suggest any corrections.

Comment: Where in the manual did you find `with nocheck`? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I'm assuming you are looking for `NOT VALID`; it goes at the very end of your query and will prevent PostgreSQL from checking existing rows against this constraint.

Comment: nocheck is SQLserver syntax and novalidate - oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you try to use Microsoft sql server syntax https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql

while Postgres syntax https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html is

`...ADD table_constraint [ NOT VALID ]`