# Adding Foreign key constraint without checking existing data in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

```
ALTER TABLE <table name> WITH NOCHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT attachments_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES public.users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

The above query is throwing the following error
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH NOCHECK"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facing error while Altering table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020552/facing-error-while-altering-table-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 4):

That appears to be SQL Server syntax. PostgreSQL doesn't support that `WITH NOCHECK`, I think you want:

```
ALTER TABLE <table name>
ADD CONSTRAINT attachments_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
REFERENCES public.users (id) NOT VALID
```

You'll have to check the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) to see if there are equivalents for the rest of the options you're trying to use.